# Set a structs' value to one of five possible

Tags: c++, struct

My classes' struct needs to be one of five values.
Right now it looks like this:

```
// Bar.h  
struct Foo{   
 string value;
}
class Bar{    
Bar(); 
}

// Bar.cpp
Bar::Bar(//magic here){
// or here
}
```

I want to set Foo to one of five values/strings as it is now (VALUEA, VALUEB,...) in the constructor, and only those five should be allowed. Its not important if the type is a string or a bool, since I just do checks on Foo if it its value == x.

How can I force the programmer to use one of the types?

Comment: So you want the value based to `Bar`'s constructor to be one of 5 values and then set a `Foo` member to that value?

Comment: Throw an exception from the constructor if an argument is not acceptable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: And then what? How would you "handle" such an exception? What's in the `catch`? If you really want to detect such an error only at runtime (which is very doubtful here), then an `assert` would be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `enum class`, not a `struct`.

```
enum class Foo {
    ValueA,
    ValueB,
    ValueC,
    ValueD,
    ValueE
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.